# WinAPI ZOrder woes

Tags: winapi, z-order

I have two windows, one smaller on top of other bigger. The window created first will always be on top. Neither `BringWindowToTop(hWnd)` nor `SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);` do nothing! I also have been trying `HWND_TOPMOST` and `HWND_BOTTOM`.

It seems the only way to make one window on top of other is a correct creation order. But this is not what I need, I need to change the order on the fly. Anyone knows what could cause this? Those are just old plain `CreateWindow()` instances both have the same parent. Any search on internet yields nothing. Need some expert help!

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

HWND make_child(HWND Parent, int x, int y, int color) {
    HINSTANCE hInstance = 0;
    MSG msg          = {0};
    WNDCLASS wc      = {0}; 
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(color);//(HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOWFRAME);
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCSTR)L"mychildwin";
    RegisterClass(&wc);
    return CreateWindow("edit",(LPCSTR)"child", WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, x,y,100,100,Parent,0,hInstance,NULL);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
    MSG msg          = {0};
    WNDCLASS wc      = {0}; 
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(0xff8080);
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCSTR)L"minwindowsapp";
    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))  return 1;
    HWND W = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName,(LPCSTR)L"Minimal Windows Application", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE, 0,0,640,480,0,0,hInstance,NULL);
    HWND A = make_child(W, 10, 10, 0x88ff00);
    HWND B = make_child(W, 70, 70, 0x8888ff);
    BringWindowToTop(B);
    SetWindowPos(B, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

    //REAL PROBLEM WAS HERE: A second call to SetWindowPos
     SetWindowPos(handle, 0, 0, 0, new_width, new_height,
      SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    // adding SWP_NOZORDER fixed it..

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) DispatchMessage(&msg);
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(message) {
        case WM_CLOSE: PostQuitMessage(0); break;
        default: return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-documentation, there is also the possibility to pass a window-handle to the window you want your window to be inserted after.

```
BOOL WINAPI SetWindowPos(
  _In_      HWND hWnd,
  _In_opt_  HWND hWndInsertAfter,
  _In_      int X,
  _In_      int Y,
  _In_      int cx,
  _In_      int cy,
  _In_      UINT uFlags
);
```

where `hWndInsertAfter` is the handle of the window your window shall be positioned **AFTER**. Have you tried this one?

Comment: Yes, passing A and B does work! But I think I am getting crazy, because the window that is closer to the user is actually the bottom window according to the behaviour of my handles.

Comment: Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx#zorder) out, might help to solve your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, maybe someone will find it really useful. Because real problem was that `SetWindowPos` and `BringWindowToTo` both worked fine, but afterwards in my real app I was calling `SetWindowPos` again to move the component a little, and it was screwing the *ZOrder* again!

So I added `SWP_NOZORDER` to that second call to `SetWindowPos`.